# Unity3D quaternion makes my local axis random

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

- Reformulated my question because it was unclear for people what i meant.

So I have a player(capsule) and I want his bottom to face to the center of the cube. The problem is that I only can get it working while losing control over my forward vector, I need my forward vector to tell my player where he can move 2. Also its not nice to see a player ingame rotating over his Y axis without a input of a controls. This is hapenning:

- The cube that the capsule is holding is the forward vector.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00BIhBHSSKQ&feature=youtu.be

The problem is that it does point to the center of the cube while moving over 1 axis but when moved over the other axis it starts acting wierd. This is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class test : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform ground;
    public Transform player;

    void Update()
    {
        Landing();
    }

    public void Landing()
    {
            Vector3 dir = ground.position - player.position;
        Quaternion rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(player.forward, -dir);

        player.rotation = rot 
    }
}
```

if I add this code however it works but I lose control over my forward direction it just keeps spinning:

```
    Quaternion bla2 = Quaternion.LookRotation(player.right, -dir);
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NO5Jpf-_pjo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to point the bottom to a point in space.

If I understand you correctly, you would want to align `bottom` vector of your player with the `dir` vector? Okay?

If I'm right you could simply use this script:

```
player.trandform.bottom = dir;
```

So, there's no need to recalculate its rotation object. Also, it's possible to follow this way for `forward`, `right`, `left`,... directions of any objects.

**Note:** You may want to animate this rotation. For this, you could use `Lerp`/`Slerp` methods of `Vector3` to have a smooth transition between this two vectors.

```
player.transform.bottom = Vector3.Lerp(player.transform.bottom, dir, Time.deltaTime * rotateSpeed);
```

Comment: Wow! I did NOT know you could do that, that is awesome! But the rotation of my object is still changing so I still have the same problemen with the foreward vector.

Comment: @MikeOttink In my experiences, in my cases you wouldn't need to re-instantiate rotation object. You can simply rotate your game objects using adjusting their direction vectors (forward, right, etc). So, stop using `obj.rotation  = Quaternion.FromToRotation` in all of your codes. Then you will have a full control over rotation of your game object. Please let me know, if something's vague.

Comment: Yes I understand that I can rotate my object by setting the direction vector only the problem still remains, because even if I set the direction vector the rotation of the object changes(I removed Quaternion.FromToRotation()). So that means that I still don't have a forward vector for my object because the object keeps rotating on the Y axis.

Comment: @MikeOttink Unfortunately I couldn't understand what you mean. However it's worh mentioning that whenever you're changing one direction of an object, all other directions might change as well. In your case by changing `bottom` direction, direction of `forward` vector will definitely change.

Comment: @MikeOttink Also this statement _" I still don't have a forward vector for my object"_ never makes sense IMO. _Every_ objects have _all_ of direction vectors under _any_ circumstances.

Comment: I will upload a video to illustrate what i mean

Comment: The cube on the capsule is the foreward vector and it keeps rotateting, I want it to keep steady. So what I need is a function that takes my foreward vector and my down vector and and rotates the player to the point without messing up the foreward vector.

Comment: @MikeOttink Which cube do you mean? that small one or that big one?

Comment: The capsule(player) has a stretched out cube inside it that points in a direction, that is the foreward vector. The point the player(capsule) is attracted to lies in the center of the big cube. The little cube is not relevant.

Comment: @MikeOttink Okay, seems I just figured out what you mean. How about parenting structure? Is your player parented with that big cube?

Comment: No it is not parented with the big cube. I do know a solution just make a parent for the player and aim te player inside that parent to the point and then use the axis of the parent to navigate. How ever I cannot use that for this assignement, so i figured that I need a function that takes the foreward direction of the player and the downward direction and finds the ideal configuration so that the Y rotation doesn't get adjusted, does that make any scence?

Comment: @MikeOttink Unfortunately no! To get a chance to find your answer, you could write your school assignment word by word, verbatim, in your question post. Then, people may understand what you want. Nevertheless, parenting would be the best solution which straightly comes to mind. But you unfortunately aren't allowed to use it in your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Like this maybe?

```
obj.Translate(speed * Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);
```

You say you want to use a custom `y`:

```
Vector3 direction = obj.forward;
direction.y = input.GetAxis("Vertical");  // < --- however you are retrieving your input I have no idea
obj.Translate(direction.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: No the vector.forward still changes.

Comment: how is that even possible, maybe try with `Space.World`

Comment: Sorry my bad, I was wrong indeed you can use the world space only then it still doenst fix my controls. Because the player is walking on cube, so he might as wel be upside down. I want the player to move on its local forward only without the Y rotation from the Quaternion.FromToRotation() but with the Y rotation that the player inputs with the controls.

Comment: Why don't you just use a parent game object for movement and then you can rotate him anyway you want but just use the parent orientation's forward to move him around, or change the `y` yourself

Comment: Because I can only use code for this assignement. I really need to fix it with code.